# What am I doing wrong - b/skipping line error in CSV file

Tags: python

I just started learning python in order to create a multipage reporting dashboard.
I'm an absolute beginner and can't find the solution to my problem.

Attached I added a screenshot of my situation :)

I had the Issue that my CSV file was too big at first(14mb) However, I managed to solve the issue by changing Pycharms settings. However, my data frame would not print. I'm not sure why it would not display any rows or columns. 
No matter what I indicate, no rows or columns are displayed. Why is it an empty data frame anyways?

I tried fixing the bad lines by using error_bad_lines and warning_bad_lines still the b/skipping line error would occur. 
When I look at my CSV datafile, the lines that are skipped seem to be just empty fields. I also tried to clean my data by replacing missing values with NaN values. Also, that seemed not to work.

I was considering to break down my CSV file in smaller CSV files in order to graph them. But I think it makes more sense to keep everything in one file due to more likely errors to happen.

I hope someone can help me out! Thanks in advance!

This is my code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_htmlcomponents as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

import csv


df= pd.read_csv(r'../datasets/Sendungenneu.csv', error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True ,sep=",",lineterminator='\n',skip_blank_lines=True,)
df.loc[0, :]

Output:
/Users/nH/NEWNEW/test/bin/python /Users/nH/NEWNEW/test/bin/Dashdash.py
b'Skipping line 14: expected 2 fields, saw 3\nSkipping line 33: expected 2 fields, saw 4\nSkipping line 50: expected 2 fields, saw 4\nSkipping line 53: expected 2 fields, saw 4\nSkipping line 94: expected 2 fields, saw 3\nSkipping line 99: expected 2 fields, saw 4\nSkipping line 105: expected 2 fields, saw 3\nSkipping line 127: expected 2 fields, saw 4\nSkipping 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Landesorganisation;Niederlassung;Modul;Sdg Anzahl;Sendungsnummer;Sendungstyp;Kostenstelle;Ladehafen (Land);Ladehafen Name;Abgangsort (UNLocode);Abgangsort (IATA Code);Abgangsort (Land);Ankunftsort (UNLocode);Ankunftsort (IATA Code);Ankunftsort (Land);Auftraggeber Geschäftspartner Name;Auftraggeber PLZ;Auftraggeber Ort;Frachtführer Name;Versender Geschäftspartner Name;Versender PLZ;Versender Ort;Empfänger Geschäftspartner Name;Empfänger PLZ;Empfänger Ort;Exportagent;Importagent;Terminal;Packschuppen;Incoterms;Frankatur;Auftragsumfang;Leistungsdatum (Jahr);Leistungsdatum (Monat);Leistungsdatum;Auftragsdatum;ETD;ETA;Transport Datum;Kolli;Bruttogewicht (kg);Frachtpflichtiges Gewicht (kg);Volumen (m³);DGR;Verkäufer;Sachbearbeiter;Verkaufsprodukt;Einkaufsprodukt;Transportart;Airline;SCI;Ocean Carrier;Linienagent Code;Linienagent;Schiff;Buchungsreferenzen;Annahmeort (IATA Code);Annahmeort (UNLocode);Annahmeort (Land);Lieferort (UNLocode);Lieferort (Land);TEU;FCL/LCL;Containertypen;Containernummern;Anzahl Container;Erwartete Erlöse;Erwartete Kosten;Offene Erlöse;Offene Kosten; Erlöse ;Kosten;Profit;Erwarteter Profit;Status erwarteter Profit;Bemerkungen]
Index: []

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Anaconda Editor 'Spyder'. You can use a thing called 'Variable Explorer' which can be used to look at datasets. And make sure you set the working directory correctly(Alongside your data file) and here is a link to the download: https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/.
It is a bit slow but you wait until it opens and then open Spyder Python IDE.